# How come Mortarboard is bronze and Enthusiast is silver?

Tags: discussion, badges

[Participation Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

```
Silver  Enthusiast    Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days   56.9k awarded
Bronze  Mortarboard   Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day      15.4k awarded
```

It would seem that earning **Enthusiast** requires almost no effort while **Mortarboard** is highly non-trivial. This appears to be reflected in the award count (almost 4:1 in favor of enthusiasts).

So, why is the first one silver and the second one bronze?

(A similar question can be asked about **Epic** vs **Fanatic** and probably many other).

Comment: Not everybody had the same internet access back then

Comment: @hjpotter92 What do you mean 'back then'? It was just a few years ago.

Comment: I'd argue that people just underestimate how easy Mortarboard really is to earn. You can earn it in a *single day*, even your very first day as a member. Enthusiast takes a minimum of 30 days. I wouldn't say the number of awards is relevant to how easy those badges are, but more to how eager users are to earn them.

Comment: Because the people who decide these things tend to be regular visitors themselves.

Comment: @animuson I would additionally argue that people overestimate how easy Enthusiast is to earn. Miss just *one day*...

Comment: For the record, I was an active member for over two years before earning the Enthusiast badge. On the other hand, I earned the Mortarboard badge within my first week. (well, technically I earned neither of these badges and no reputation for my first several months, but I wasn't really active during that point -- just had an account). Andrew Barber is right -- I kept missing just *one day*.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: come on - a wget cron job will do that for you ;-)

Comment: As noted before; if someone wants to go to the trouble to get that to work, they probably deserve the badge. It's fairly easy to do it - but not as easy as most people think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Badges should encourage good behaviour.

Coming back every day is more important **for the site** than hitting 200 rep on a single day.

Comment: more ad revenue.

Comment: @ChrisGerken haha! Yes; and getting lots of rep can reduce that (when you reach the level to reduce ads!) ;-)